# Trying to draw to the screen using pygame, cant get any method to work

Tags: python, pygame, pixel

This is a snippet of my code that takes a text input and plots pixels to the screen, this is the command format
!pixel 32,32 255,255,255

```
##Command Format !Pixel X,Y R,G,B
def screencontrol():
##now we open the PyGame window
(width, height) = (256, 256) #more window setup
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #more window setup
pygame.display.flip() #more window setup
global message
#global splitmsg
while True:
    commandmessage = message
    pygame.init()
    pygame.event.pump() ##keeps pygame window refreshed / not crash
    if "!pixel" == commandmessage.lower().split(" ", 1)[0]: #Split message and check for pixel command
        print("Received a draw pixel request!") #debug output

        coordsforpix = commandmessage.lower().split(" ", -1)[1]
        print("Extracting draw... ")
        plotpixx = coordsforpix.split(",", 2)[0]
        print("X = " + plotpixx)
        plotpixy =coordsforpix.split(",", 2)[1]
        print("Y = " + plotpixy)
        plotpixrgb = commandmessage.lower().split(" ", -1)[2]
        print("RGB = " + plotpixrgb)
        plotpixr = plotpixrgb.split(",", 3)[0]
        plotpixg =plotpixrgb.split(",", 3)[1]
        plotpixb =plotpixrgb.split(",", 3)[2]
        print("R G B = " + plotpixr + plotpixg + plotpixb)
        print("Done extracting")
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, tuple(map(int, plotpixrgb.split(",", -1))), (int(plotpixx), int(plotpixy)),  1)#plot point
        commandmessage = ""
        message = ""
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days trying to make it work, everything else works perfectly, debugging outputs what it should but it just won't plot any pixels...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) updates the full display Surface to the screen and has to be done at the end of the application loop, but [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) initialize all imported pygame modules and has to be done only once. It has to be the 1st pygame instruction.

```py
def screencontrol():

    pygame.init() # init pygame

    ##now we open the PyGame window
    (width, height) = (256, 256) #more window setup
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) # create window

    global message
    #global splitmsg
    while True:
        commandmessage = message
        pygame.event.pump() ##k

        if "!pixel" == commandmessage.lower().split(" ", 1)[0]:
            # [...]

        pygame.display.flip() # update display at the end of the loop
```